# simple database handling applicatication with Kohana

Tags: insert, records

Can somebody help me with database handling applications like insert a record, edit etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read through the Kohana 101 in the wiki. It gives a great overview about those stuff (and quite some more).

[You can find it here.](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101)